# Using a a lifted data type on the right of => in ghci

Tags: haskell, data-kinds

Consider the following code

```
{-# LANGUAGE ConstraintKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module Test () where

type C x = x ~ 1
type family F x = r where
  F 0 = 0
  F 1 = 2
  F 2 = 4
```

I am trying to convince gchi to solve `:kind! forall x . C x => F x`
into `2`. But it looks like I can only use Type kinded stuff on the
right of `=>`. Is there a way to get around that? In particular I get

```
<interactive>:1:20: error:
    • Expected a type, but ‘F x’ has kind ‘GHC.Types.Nat’
    • In the type ‘forall x. C x => F x’
```

EDIT: wrapping it in proxy does not seem to work:

```
:kind! (forall x . C x => Proxy (F x))
(forall x . C x => Proxy (F x)) :: *
= C x => Proxy (F x)
```

Comment: You can't - if you want to be very pedantic, then `=>` has kind `Constraint -> Type -> Type`, so the rhs would have to be a type. For simple testing like it seems you are trying to do, wrapping the rhs in `Proxy` is the correct thing to do (in practice, you cannot make use of your `F` type family without employing some type whose kind is `Nat -> Type`). `kind!` does not solve constraints - it just normalizes types (try e.g. `:kind! (1 ~ 2) => ()` - nothing happens. but `:t () :: (1 ~ 2) => ()` gives a type error) - this is completely unrelated, however.

Comment: Types that aren't in kind `*` (or kind `#`) are not inhabited, so you cannot ever have a value of that type (which, I imagine, is a big part of why that sort of thing is automatically rejected).